# Replace a unique value in a Xarray.DataArray

Tags: python, arrays, python-xarray

I want to replace a unique value of a `Xarray.DataArray` but every code that I tried it didn't work. It's very easy:

```
np.min(cape2) = 0.0001
```

So, I want to replace this result to 0, i.e., np.min(cape2) = 0.

I tried with `cape2.where(cape2  > 0.0002, 0)` and `cape2.where(cape2  != 0.0002, 0)`, but didn't work.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done this way

```
import numpy as np
x=np.array([1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,7,8])
print(x)
x[x==np.min(x)]=0
print(x)

[1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 7 8]
[0 2 3 4 5 0 2 3 7 8]
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't replace a value in that way. If you want to replace a value of an array then you have to use proper indexing to replace that value. Let's say, we have a ndarray of unique values. Let's call it "arr" and we want to replace the minimum value with a different one, as you tried, then we may do this.

```
arr = np.array([2, 5, 6, 1, 10]) # our array of unique values
idx = np.where(arr == np.min(arr)) # get the index of the minimum value;

print(idx) # reutrns (array([3], dtype=int64),)
# we can access the index as idx[0][0]
print(idx[0]) # returns [3]
print(idx[0][0]) # returns 3
print(arr[idx[0][0]]) # returns 1
arr[idx[0][0]] = 50 # replace 1 with 50
print(arr[idx[0][0]]) # returns 50
print(arr) # returns [2, 5, 6, 50, 10]
```

Hope, this will help you solve your problem.